# Export to Excel for 1 table from all linked tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have Table1, which is linked to many other tables using PK/FK. Now I want to create export of all records from Table1, and for each record of Table1 display all values from other tables in Excel AND NOT JUST A FK in fields that are FK. Problem is here - I have some records in Table1 that have all fields fullfilled (including those that are FK), and some not. So, those FK fields which are not linked to other tables are blank, and Access shows in Query only linked records.

Any idea on what I can do to make Access show all data in one row of Excel spreadsheet?

EDIT:

My tables (Table Employee is linked 4 times with table APPS - FK_fields, but Access shows only 1 relationship)

[image]

My output should have all those fields from table APPS in 1 row, BUT WITH ALL linked table fields instead of FK_fields values. Example for 1 row (desired output order followed by tables APPS-SUPPLIERS-EMPLOYEES-VERSION-HARDWARE-APPS_HARDWARE):

1234|Access|Programme|YES|Microsoft|14th Street, L.A.|Mike Brown|David Fox|John Long|Sally Sugar|25.08.2016|Ver.1|1st version|25.08.2016(version date)|PC|desktop computer|25.08.2016(hardware date)|Valid for use|25.08.2016(APPS-HARDWARE record date)

Comment: Are you creating a query using the query builder or writing the SQL?

Comment: I'm doing both, in query builder. But so far I managed to display only records from Table1 that are matched on all linked tables.

Comment: Ok, if you right click on the relationship line between Table1 and Table2 and choose "Join Properties" you can select to have all records from Table1 in your query even if there are no matching records in Table1

Comment: @MichaelRusso,thanks, but that solves problem only If there are 2 tables. I have Table1 linked with 4 different tables, and when I try to "Join Properties" on all for Table1 I get error:"The SQL statement could not be executed because it contains ambigious outer joins. To force one of the joins to be performed first, create a separate query that performs the first join and then include that query in your SQL".

Comment: could you post some information about the tables and the result that you are looking for

Comment: sure, give me 10 minutes for that

Comment: take a look at edited question.

Comment: take a look again, better now, I posted image of DB.

Comment: Thanks for help, I managed to sort It out, It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to study and use **table joins**, left and/or right joins. A left join says show me all the data from the table written to the left even if there are no matching record(s) from the table on the right. A simple example,

```
SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2...
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.common_field = table2.common_field;
```

The missing data will be populated with NULLs.

[SQL - LEFT JOINS](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-left-joins.htm)

---

If you are using Access's Query Design View you can take advantage of it to help create the SQL statement. I would put the main table to the left, and have the joined tables fanned out to the right. Double-click the join lines to modify them to left or right joins.

You'll end up with something like this, although it requires some formatting to display neatly:

```
SELECT
  tblStaff.FirstName, tblOffices.OfficeName, tblDepts.Department,
  tblHolidays.FirstDate
FROM (tblOffices
RIGHT JOIN (tblDepts
RIGHT JOIN tblStaff
  ON tblDepts.DeptID = tblStaff.Department)
  ON tblOffices.OfficeID = tblStaff.OfficeID)
LEFT JOIN tblHolidays
  ON tblStaff.StaffID = tblHolidays.StaffID;
```

[image]

Comment: Here's a Documentation link, [differences between joins](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/261/join/14930/differences-between-sql-joins#t=201608251203567842533).

Comment: thanks Andy, I know something about left joins, but how to make left join on multiple tables for 1 table?

Comment: I've added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks andy, very close to what I need. But, what If I "Grade","Salary" and "Bonus" would be all linked  with "tblDepts" ? That is problem I have, 1 table is linked 4 times with Table1 (names and surnames of tehnician,administrator,user,maintainer for same app). And not only that - I have 1 many-to-many relationship too.

Comment: Can you tell me how you posted picture here, I will show my DB design, It's hard for me  to explain in words ?

Comment: Use the image button to add an image to your question

Comment: Ok, see my edited question now. I hope you'll get It.